# Identical key in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an textfield where you can add comma separated values: Address1, Adress2

When you hit submit, information will be returned for each adress you typed in.

I want to treat the information as an array, and use the separated values that user user entered, as keys in the array.

I have the following code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $addresses = explode(",", $_POST['addresses']);
    $ort = $_POST['omrade'];
    $obj = array();

    foreach($addresses as $address)
    {
        echo $newSpider->fetchPage($address, $ort, $offst=0);

        if(!isset($obj[$address]))
        {
            $obj[$address] = array();

            echo "<pre>";
            var_dump($address);
            echo "</pre>";
        }
    }
}
```

When I type in two values, Adress1 and Adress2, the output of var_dump is:

```
array(1) {
  ["Address1"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}

array(2) {
  ["Address1"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["Address2"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

I want it to be like this:

```
array(1) {
  ["Address1"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["Address2"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Anyone who can help me and explain?

Comment: If you move the var dump outside the loop you should see the expected output

Comment: Also, your var dump will NEVER show array(1) if you are putting in two arrays, it will show array(2) because there are two entries in the array.

Comment: That is going to give you A LOT of headaches. What will happen if someone needs to enter a comma? It will be better if you sent an html array to PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code basically var_dumps for every loop. Just var_dump it after loop. Try this

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
$addresses = explode(",", $_POST['addresses']);
$ort = $_POST['omrade'];
$obj = array();

foreach($addresses as $address)
{
    echo $newSpider->fetchPage($address, $ort, $offst=0);

    if(!isset($obj[$address]))
    {
        $obj[$address] = array();

        echo "<pre>";

        echo "</pre>";
    }
}
var_dump($address);
}
```

Comment: Your are welcome, if it worked then upvote and mark it as answer. Which helps others.